# Jquery Mobile weird space appears when I click blank areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my first time doodling with jquery-mobile. I designed a theme, and now I'm trying to implement it...

Things aren't going as smooth as expected, while I've good understanding of jquery/javascript in general, I really don't like working with frameworks with their quirks and specific syntax.

**Anyhow, please check:** http://mac.idev.ge:800/html5-mobile/iradio.html

**Problem:**
Try to click in the area of the player, on the album cover for example, notice how blank space appears on the top of lyrics area? What is that? Same happens if you click near song title..

*This is baffling...*

Any ideas how to fix this unwanted behaviour? And what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to your header/content div

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

There are a couple of questions related to this problem:

[Jquery mobile: Disable "tap to toggle" fixed header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232415/jquery-mobile-disable-tap-to-toggle-fixed-header-and-footer)

[How to fix jQuery Mobile's fixed footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377062/how-to-fix-jquery-mobiles-fixed-footer)

They seem to depend on which version you are using but give them a try

Comment: Thanks for additional info :)